# AngularJS $LogProvider throws Illegal access error

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, android-webview, firefox-os

I have a mobile app that uses cordova + [AngularJS 1.2.4](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular.js) It works perfect on every platform I tested except some Android 2.3.X devices throw a mysterious `illegal access` exception. Below is the portion of code that raises the error. Precisely speaking, the line `return logFn.apply(console, args);` seems to be the culprit. If I remove the parameter `args` code works fine. It seems odd since variable `args` is defined at the top of the function. I don't understand what is really causing this `illegal access` error? Any one had a similar problem? Any ideas how to fix it?

ps: Please check out inline comments to better understand the problem. There, I debugged and reported some cases.

```
    function consoleLog(type) {
      var console = $window.console || {},
          logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop;
      if (logFn.apply) {
        return function() {
          var args = [];
          forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
            args.push(formatError(arg));
            // console.log(typeof arg); -> prints string
            // console.log(arg.toString); -> prints function
            // console.log(arg); -> throws illegal access error
            // console.log(arg.toString()); -> throws illegal access error
          });
          // console.log(args); -> throws illegal access error
          // return logFn.apply(console); -> works fine w/o `args`
          return logFn.apply(console, args); -> throws illegal access error
        };
      }

      // we are IE which either doesn't have window.console => this is noop and we do nothing,
      // or we are IE where console.log doesn't have apply so we log at least first 2 args
      return function(arg1, arg2) {
        logFn(arg1, arg2 == null ? '' : arg2);
      };
    }
```

Comment: Do you know, what exactly is contained in this log message? Are there any messages, that succeeded to be logged?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Error shows up in the console right after bootstrapping the app. I don't know the caller and passed arguments.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Firefox OS too. I'm trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: @Aleyna could you find the fix for it?

Comment: I'd like to know as well...

Answer (score 0):

The code, you posted isn't the problem. This is Angular's built-in Exception handling. I made the same mistake and tried to dig in here, but Angular's Exception Handlings works fine.

But there is a [reported Issue (Github)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1241) concerning Android 2.3.x and Firefox OS in 1.2.4 and they fixed it in 1.2.5

Maybe you should try a higher AngularJS Version