# AngularJS $LogProvider throws File Error in Firefox OS 1.1

Tags: angularjs, exception, cordova, firefox-os

I have a Cordova app that runs Angular 1.2.16. It runs perfectly on all platforms and browsers except on Firefox OS **1.1**. Works well on Firefox OS **1.2**.

Please see linked SO article which has test cases - I have the same problem, but instead get

```
[Exception... "File error: Not found"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: app://054daea0-e3bf-1d40-a545-3ea97484180e/js/app-ck.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 17214"  data: no]
```

A later javascript error just says "Syntax Error" without referencing anywhere. I suspect it's related to this issue.

Related article, :

[AngularJS $LogProvider throws Illegal access error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196494/angularjs-logprovider-throws-illegal-access-error)

Please, if anyone could give a hint to what's breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The source file (app-ck.js) cannot be found. The syntax error is due to the failed attempt to link to a file that does not exist. Firefox OS 1.1 uses [Firefox 18](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/18), whereas Firefox OS 1.2 uses [Firefox 26](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/26). Test the Angular code for your app on both Firefox versions on the desktop via [Firefox Profiles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiple_profiles) to confirm.

**References**

- [Mozilla Bug 971644 – JavascriptException: JavascriptException: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND raised during setup](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=971644)
- [App manifest - Archive of obsolete content | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_apps/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/Manifest)
- [Test App Validation | Developers | Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/validator)